# Sub query subtraction - SQL

Tags: sql, dataset

This works:

```
SELECT Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account, SUM([12.31.2017_YTD]) AS Q1
FROM [2017DB]
WHERE (Date = '2017-06-30')
GROUP BY Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account
```

I'm trying to output the difference between that select statement and an identical select statement, only the second select statement would have a date of 03-31.

I believe this would be achieved through a subquery, but I'm a beginner and having some difficulty structuring it.

This does not work:

```
Select(
    SELECT Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account, SUM([12.31.2017_YTD]) AS Q1
    FROM [2017DB]
    WHERE (Date = '2017-06-30'))
- 
    SELECT Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account, SUM([12.31.2017_YTD]) AS Q1
    FROM [2017DB]
    WHERE (Date = '2017-03-31'))

    GROUP BY Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account


Data >  Date    Prop_Code   MBA_Account 12.31.2017_YTD
        3/31/2017   Balt    Administrative  100
        3/31/2017   Balt    Administrative  100
        6/30/2017   Balt    Administrative  500
        6/30/2017   Balt    Administrative  500


Desired result >        Prop_Code   MBA_Account Q2
            Balt    Administrative  800
```

The desired result would be the calculation of:
sum(6/30 YTD records) - sum(3/31 YTD records)

Code that ultimately worked was a version of Gordon's suggestion below:

```
SELECT Prop_Code, MBA_Account,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = '2017-09-30' THEN [12.31.2017_YTD] END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = '2017-06-30' THEN [12.31.2017_YTD] END) AS 'Q3'
FROM [2017DB].[dbo].[2017DB]
Group by Prop_Code, MBA_Account
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = '2017-03-31' THEN [12.31.2017_YTD] END) AS Q1_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = '2017-06-30' THEN [12.31.2017_YTD] END)) AS Q1_2
FROM [2017DB]
WHERE Date IN ('2017-06-30', '2017-03-31')
GROUP BY Date, Prop_Code, MBA_Account;
```

The difference would just be the difference of the `SUM()` expressions.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon, I was able to use a version of your code to produce the desired results.  I've added the final code to my original post.